# Is artificial life valued in the DC universe?

Tags: dc

To what extent is artificial life valued in the DCU?

I ask because I've seen Superman destroy (kill?) what seemed to be sentient artificial lifeforms.

Are there any examples of sentient life being considered as sacred as organic life? Or in general is artificial life considered less valuable and OK to be destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Artificial life has no particular rights on the DC Universe's [New Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DC_Multiverse_worlds). Even beneficial machines like [Brother Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMAC_%28comics%29) or [Red Tornado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Tornado) are treated with fear and suspicion.**

How artificial life is treated outside of the Earth varies depending on the cultural viewpoints of the species. The Guardians created the artificially intelligent [Manhunters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhunters) to patrol the Universe before they created the Green Lantern Corp.

[image]

The Green Lantern Corps had at least one mechanical intelligence called [Stel](http://www.comicvine.com/stel/29-47279/).

[image]

I don't think the average human on DC Earth believe artificial intelligence has any particular merit. Consider most human's experience with hostile robots, dangerous cyborgs or artificially intelligent machines ([The Shaggy Man](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Shaggy_Man_I_%28New_Earth%29), [Amazo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazo), [Red Torpedo](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Torpedo_%28New_Earth%29), [Metallo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallo) (cyborg), [Brainaic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainiac_%28comics%29), [Henry Henshaw](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Henry_Henshaw_%28New_Earth%29) (cyborg), [The Eradicator](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Eradicator_%28New_Earth%29), the host of robots created by the [Toyman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Toyman)) they are destructive and dangerous forces. This may cause most humans to prefer humans over any other kind of sentience.

[image]

Superman, for all of his extraterrestrial origins, he was raised on Earth and has all the same kinds of viewpoints of most humans, particularly in the New 52 DCnU. He may not have an enlightened view of artificial intelligence this early in his career.